# Express server send empty PDF file

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I have a route that sends a pdf file:

```
app.get('/teste',function(req,res,next){
    res.setHeader('content-type','application/pdf');
    res.download(app.get('appPath')+'/teste.pdf');
}
```

I tried use another solutions that do more or less the same thing:

```
app.get('/teste',function(req,res,next){
    res.setHeader('content-type','application/pdf');
    fs.createReadStream(app.get('appPath')+'/teste.pdf').pipe(res);
 }
```

and

```
app.get('/teste',function(req,res,next){
        res.setHeader('content-type','application/pdf');
        res.sendfile(app.get('appPath')+'/teste.pdf');
}
```

My problem is when I ask this route in browser and I receive an empty pdf file with the same number of pages that the original file.

I configured my express server with `app.use(express.bodyParser());`.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've seen this when using connect-livereload middleware.  The problem is that connect-livereload is injecting a js code snippet into the pdf data stream.  It can also cause problems with other non-html data.  The good news is that this should only cause problems during development (you shouldn't be loading this middleware in production.)

This was recently fixed but a lot of templates include an older version so check your package.json file and get the latest version if necessary.  The most recent connect-livereload version is 0.5.3.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the problem. I had to upload pdf files to the cloud to pass around the problem :S

Comment: ARggghhh I've spent all day looking at this, and just stumbled over your comment. Updating connect-livereload to 0.5.3 didn't fix it for me - disabling it completely did!!! What a waste of a day, and thank you so much... this is rediculous

Answer (score 0):

If the e.g. `ignore: ['.pdf']` line does not work, it might be due to fact that you do not query for a resource with the related suffix.

E.g. If you query for a resource with an id:

```
localhost:9000/api/export/getExport?destinationId=56179bb36bc51bb00836c3ed
```

you cannot filter for the file suffix. What you can do instead is to filter via the path:

```
app.use( require( 'connect-livereload' )( {
  ignore: [ /api\/export\/getExport.*/ ]
} ) );
```

Have a look at the other possible options at [connect-livereload](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload#options).