# Piping a file results on a blank file

Tags: node.js, download, pipe

I have this piece of code in my nodejs app:

```
function (req, res) {
  var serviceUrl = 'http://backend-server:8080/files/123';
  require('request').get(serviceUrl).pipe(res);
}
```

If put http://backend-server:8080/files/123 on the browser it downloads a .pdf file. But when I go through nodejs, it also downloads a .pdf file, but the file is empty.

I can't understand why.

**UPDATE**: The problem was the connect-livereload middleware. Consider this a duplicate question for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412919/express-server-send-empty-pdf-file)

Comment: What output do you get when you run this command on the same machine that nodejs is running on?  curl -v http://backend-server:8080/files/123 | wc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express server send empty PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412919/express-server-send-empty-pdf-file)

Comment: Did you fix this?