# Issue while requesting a file(image/pdf/excel sheet) from server and then pipe to res

Tags: node.js, express, request, cloudinary

**Scenario:**

I have to send user file which is stored remotely in a server(cloudinary) to browser. I'm able to request an image from server and then pipe it to browser but it's not working for other files like pdf, excel sheet, etc.

```
exports.fetchFile = function(req, res, next){
var fileUrl = "/" + req.params.fileUrl;
console.log(fileUrl);

async.auto({
    'A': function(callback) {
        var queryObj = { 'myUrl' : fileUrl};
        // DB Query to retrieve user file information like url, type, etc.
        UserFileCtrl.fetchUserFile(queryObj, callback);
    }
}, function(err, results){
    if(err) {
        return res.send(500, "error");
    }

    var secureUrl = results['A']['secureUrl'];
    var fileType = results['A']['fileType'];
    // this will be "application/pdf" for pdf
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType);

    request(secureUrl).pipe(res);
}); 
}
```

Above code gives an empty pdf file to client whereas if I open directly the cloudinary url then it's coming properly. I'm breaking my head for a long time but not able to get something out of it.

I really appreciate your help.

Edit: I found this similar question also: [Express server send empty PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412919/express-server-send-empty-pdf-file) but this is also not working for me. I tried disabling connnect-livereload but even then it's not working.

The issue is happening only for pdfs. All other formats are working fine.

Comment: Hi, can you share such URLs of PDF that fail to display on the browser?
Note that `content-type` header usually serves within POST/PUT requests rather than within GET requests (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: @NadavOfir: But request(secureUrl).pipe(res); this should do the trick, right ? I'm passing the response as it's without any manipulation. Though the number of pages are same but they all are just empty.

Comment: @darkShadow: Can you share a URL to PDF file that fails to load?
If privacy is an issue, you can [open a support ticket](http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with Cloudinary and the tech-support team will be happy to assist further.